# How can I choose "at least n" of each type of item in an ordered list

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting

I have a list of results (see **JSON** below), and I need to choose the top 10.  Here they're in json but I'm json_decoding them into an array like $coureValues["BUS1067"] == 117.1

I use arsort($courseValues) to get them in order like **JSON** below.

I need to choose the top 10, but I need to enforce a constraint of at least 4 "BUS", at least 2 "CMP", and at least 1 SAF.   So for example, if there is no SAFxxxx in the top 10, but there are 6 BUS and 2 CMP, I want to remove the lowest scoring BUS and add the highest scoring SAF.  In the end, all I want is a php array with the top 10, taking into consideration the constraints.

**JSON**

```
{
    "BUS1067": 117.1,
    "BUS1057": 86.06,
    "BUS1073": 79,
    "BUS1068": 74.08,
    "BUS1077": 74,
    "BUS1001": 71,
    "BUS1066": 68,
    "BUS1076": 67.05,
    "BUS1011": 64,
    "BUS1054": 64,
    "BUS1006": 63,
    "CMP1091": 62,
    "BUS1000": 60,
    "CMP1083": 59,
    "SAF1007": 58,
    "CMP1073": 56,
    "CMP1044": 55,
    "CMP1029": 55,
    "CMP1082": 53,
    "CMP1089": 50,
    "CMP1042": 48,
    "CMP1070": 46,
    "CMP1074": 45,
    "BUS1074": 31,
    "BUS1009": 20,
    "BUS1003": 10,
    "BUS1058": 1.09,
    "BUS1061": 1.07,
    "BUS1056": 1.04,
    "CMP1081": 1.03,
    "SAF1021": 1.01,
    "CMP1064": 0,
    "CMP1039": 0,
    "CMP1047": 0,
    "SAF1045": 0,
    "SAF1047": 0,
    "CMP1063": 0,
    "SAF1020": 0,
    "SAF1043": 0,
    "SAF1032": 0,
    "SAF1038": 0,
    "BUS1075": 0,
    "SAF1002": 0,
    "CMP1037": 0,
    "BUS1040": 0,
    "CMP1078": 0,
    "BUS1013": 0,
    "CMP1080": 0,
    "BUS1002": 0,
    "BUS1048": 0,
    "BUS1071": 0,
    "CMP1072": 0,
    "CMP1088": 0,
    "CMP1084": 0,
    "BUS1031": 0,
    "BUS1055": 0,
    "BUS1063": 0,
    "BUS1072": 0,
    "SAF1013": 0,
    "BUS1012": 0,
    "SAF1006": 0,
    "CMP1049": -20,
    "CMP1048": -20,
    "CMP1050": -20,
    "CMP1075": -20,
    "CMP1038": -925,
    "CMP1041": -929,
    "CMP1079": -933.98
    }
```

what I'm looking for is a simple, elegant way to do that.  I could "get it done", but the code that comes to mind is messy and unclear, and it seems that there's some general "algorithm" or sorting function that I should be using.

**UPDATE:** CODE:
as requested, here is my awful code to do a simple thing

```
<?php

$jsonWeights='{ "BUS1067": 117.1, "BUS1057": 86.06, "BUS1073": 79, "BUS1068": 74.08, "BUS1077": 74, "BUS1001": 71, "BUS1066": 68, "BUS1076": 67.05, "BUS1011": 64, "BUS1054": 64, "BUS1006": 63, "CMP1091": 62, "BUS1000": 60, "CMP1083": 59, "SAF1007": 58, "CMP1073": 56, "CMP1044": 55, "CMP1029": 55, "CMP1082": 53, "CMP1089": 50, "CMP1042": 48, "CMP1070": 46, "CMP1074": 45, "BUS1074": 31, "BUS1009": 20, "BUS1003": 10, "BUS1058": 1.09, "BUS1061": 1.07, "BUS1056": 1.04, "CMP1081": 1.03, "SAF1021": 1.01, "CMP1064": 0, "CMP1039": 0, "CMP1047": 0, "SAF1045": 0, "SAF1047": 0, "CMP1063": 0, "SAF1020": 0, "SAF1043": 0, "SAF1032": 0, "SAF1038": 0, "BUS1075": 0, "SAF1002": 0, "CMP1037": 0, "BUS1040": 0, "CMP1078": 0, "BUS1013": 0, "CMP1080": 0, "BUS1002": 0, "BUS1048": 0, "BUS1071": 0, "CMP1072": 0, "CMP1088": 0, "CMP1084": 0, "BUS1031": 0, "BUS1055": 0, "BUS1063": 0, "BUS1072": 0, "SAF1013": 0, "BUS1012": 0, "SAF1006": 0, "CMP1049": -20, "CMP1048": -20, "CMP1050": -20, "CMP1075": -20, "CMP1038": -925, "CMP1041": -929, "CMP1079": -933.98 }';

$courseValues=json_decode($jsonWeights,true);
arsort($courseValues);

$minRequired=array("BUS"=>4, "CMP"=>2, "SAF"=>1);
$pathLength=10;
$selected=array();

//get top results to satisfy minimum required
foreach ($minRequired as $courseType => $min) {
    foreach($courseValues as $key => $val){
        if(substr($key, 0, 3) == $courseType && $min)
        {
            $selected[$key]=$val;
            $min--;
            if($min==0)
                break;
        }
    }
}


//fill in the remaining with the top results
foreach($courseValues as $k=>$v){
    if(count($selected)<$pathLength)
    {
        if(!array_key_exists($k, $selected))
            $selected[$k]=$v;
    }
    else
        break;
}

arsort($selected);

foreach($selected as $k=>$v)
    echo "$k: $v<br>";

?>
```

Comment: Can't you show us that "messy" code that you have already?

Comment: @AndiPower heh, fair enough as this is stack overflow, but man, you're gonna make me right 15 lines of shameful code and post it on the internet!   If that's what it takes end up with good code, though, I'll be glad...

Comment: @AndiPower OK, I posted the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MY SOLUTION:**

Ok, I've got it down to one foreach loop.  here's the full solution:

```
$jsonWeights='{ "BUS1067": 117.1, "BUS1057": 86.06, "BUS1073": 79, "BUS1068": 74.08, "BUS1077": 74, "BUS1001": 71, "BUS1066": 68, "BUS1076": 67.05, "BUS1011": 64, "BUS1054": 64, "BUS1006": 63, "CMP1091": 62, "BUS1000": 60, "CMP1083": 59, "SAF1007": 58, "CMP1073": 56, "CMP1044": 55, "CMP1029": 55, "CMP1082": 53, "CMP1089": 50, "CMP1042": 48, "CMP1070": 46, "CMP1074": 45, "BUS1074": 31, "BUS1009": 20, "BUS1003": 10, "BUS1058": 1.09, "BUS1061": 1.07, "BUS1056": 1.04, "CMP1081": 1.03, "SAF1021": 1.01, "CMP1064": 0, "CMP1039": 0, "CMP1047": 0, "SAF1045": 0, "SAF1047": 0, "CMP1063": 0, "SAF1020": 0, "SAF1043": 0, "SAF1032": 0, "SAF1038": 0, "BUS1075": 0, "SAF1002": 0, "CMP1037": 0, "BUS1040": 0, "CMP1078": 0, "BUS1013": 0, "CMP1080": 0, "BUS1002": 0, "BUS1048": 0, "BUS1071": 0, "CMP1072": 0, "CMP1088": 0, "CMP1084": 0, "BUS1031": 0, "BUS1055": 0, "BUS1063": 0, "BUS1072": 0, "SAF1013": 0, "BUS1012": 0, "SAF1006": 0, "CMP1049": -20, "CMP1048": -20, "CMP1050": -20, "CMP1075": -20, "CMP1038": -925, "CMP1041": -929, "CMP1079": -933.98 }';
$courseValues=json_decode($jsonWeights,true);
arsort($courseValues);

$required=array("BUS"=>4, "CMP"=>2, "SAF"=>1,"Total" => 10);
$selected=array();
foreach($required as $type => $min)
    foreach($courseValues as $key => $val)
        if(count($selected)<$required['Total'] 
        &&($type=='Total'||(substr($key,0,3)==$type && $min-->0)))
            $selected[$key]=$val;
```

I'll leave it open in case anyone has a better idea

Answer (score 0):

<del>$topten = array_keys( array_slice( arsort( $courseValues ), 0, 10) );</del> ?

okay, sorry for not reading the question thoroughly :)

Comment: how does this enforce the constraint of at least 2 CMP and 1 SAF?

Comment: I think I've been in a similiar situation and I believe there's no other way than looping through the original (sorted) array, use some ifs to put the array elements to a new array, and break when the new array has 10 elements.

Comment: yeah, but some guys are pretty awesome. They'll convert it to one string and use a little regex and do it all in like 3 lines of code

Answer (score 0):

I would start with creating a php array that has the prefixes as keys and the number needed as values like so:

```
$prefixes = array("BUS" => 4, "CMP" => 2, "SAF" => 1);
```

Then, since you need 10 elements and the sum of the values is 7, you pick 3 elements from any category. The loop then should be something like this:

---

**Basic idea:**

While you don't have 10 elements from the sorted list:

Get element.

Extract prefix.

If (the prefix exists in the prefix array, and the corresponding value is greater than 0),
    or (the sum of the remaining prefix values is less than the number of elements needed), then add it to your result.

---

**In code:**

```
$results = array();
foreach ($courseValues as $course => $courseValue) {
    $prefix = substr($course, 0, 3);
    if (isset($prefixes[$prefix]) && $prefixes[$prefix--] >= 0) {
        $results[$course] = $courseValue;
    }
    else if (array_sum($prefixes) < 10 - count($results)) {
        $results[$course] = $courseValue;
    }

    if (count($results) == 10) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Note: this is assuming $courseValues is sorted by $courseValue

Comment: yeah, I had started with that array.  But I don't just want any 3 elements, I want the top elements.  I posted code now, so you can see something similar, but it's extremely verbose and I'm positive this can all be done in a much simpler and elegant way

Comment: If you first sort the elements, then this would retrieve the top elements.